# iPhone Onboarding screen in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

In the official Human Interface Guidelines Apple is reference the topic onboarding - a neat interface which only pops up when you open the app for the first time. 
I‘ve seen this in many apps, yet I can‘t find information on how to implement it. It seems like a standardized interface. Check it out here: https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/app-architecture/onboarding/

Can anybody provide some information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no ready-made components in UIKit specifically for onboarding views. You'll have to roll your own.